# can't compare dirent->d_type to DT_DIR

Tags: c, dirent.h

I am trying to do a simple comparison to be able to do something if the file type read is a directory.

Sample code :

```
int main()
{
  DIR *dir = opendir(".");
  struct dirent *dirent = readdir(dir);
  if (dirent->d_type == DT_DIR)
    //do something
  return 0;
}
```

Here is says:

> `DT_DIR` not initialised

When I try to use brackets around as such: `"DT_DIR"` I get the following errors:

- > comparing pointer and integer
- > comparison with string literal results in undefined behavior

If I understand correctly I need to put `DT_DIR` in a `char` array? This is the first time I'm using these structs and functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The macro `DT_DIR` is not part of the POSIX but a glibc extension. Define 
`#define _GNU_SOURCE` at the top before including headers to get it (or define `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` if your glibc version is >= 2.19). In fact `d_type` isn't even mentioned in POSIX's [definition of `struct dirent`.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/dirent.h.html)